# Guaranteed ordering of messages across a Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have read dozens of articles about Kafka message ordering and still don't see an out-of-the-box solution to my very common need - publishing messages with a sequentially-incrementing ID and consuming them in that same order.

Kafka preserves message order within a partition.  But what enterprise-grade solution would ever use a single partition for critical data (single point of data loss failure, reduced throughput without parallelism, etc.)?  So the challenge is how to consume messages in order across a multi-partitioned topic.

Doing blockchain analytics, we harvest sequentially-incrementing blocks of data from blockchain nodes and then publish them to our Kafka topic.  `Key` = block number, `Value` = block data.  Block numbers start at 0 and increment by 1 for eternity.

Our analytics code needs to consume those messages IN ORDER (block 1, block 2, block 3, etc.).  If a Smart contract get created on a blockchain in block 2 and then a transaction on it occurs in block 3, our analytics code would fail if we processed block 3 before block 2 ("no contract found error", for example).

Some more info about our use case.

1. The topic with block data will never be purged.  This will grow to several TB and will have millions of messages on it.  Though most consumers won't use this directly, it still servers as our off-chain copy of a blockchain and may fulfill future needs within our software.
2. We have a SQL database table which stores the stateful information about how much of a blockchain we've analyzed (example, highest block # is 25,555,555).

For guaranteed ordering, most articles recommend Kafka Streams and KTables.  If we use in-memory KTables, then we face major challenges (can't store TB of data in-memory, rebuilding the KTable at startup would take days, etc.)

If we use persisted KTables, then we're bloating our disk usage (several TB of data duplicated across the source topic and the KTable).

We can create a secondary "operational" single-partition topic [with a relatively short data retention time] and stream the data to that in order, and then have our consumers pull data from that topic.  But this is exactly the opposite of out-of-the-box and we'd like to avoid doing this for the hundreds of blockchains and messaging needs we have.  It'll become and administrative debacle.

This seems like a technical need that thousands of companies have had since the creation of Kafka (like what messaging queues have done for decades).  Is there no out-of-the-box solution for a KafkaListener to receive messages in order based on a numeric Key [in a multi-partition topic]?

Comment: That is not how the key is intended to be used; generally people use the key to ensure strict ordering for that key only; records with different keys can go to different partitions, but all records with the same key go, in order, to a single partition.

Comment: @GaryRussell  Good point.  Is there a different mechanism in Kafka that may suit our needs better?  Can we add this "key" somewhere else?  I previously built a JMS-based solution and put incrementally-incrementing message IDs into a message header.  But I don't think this would work in Kafka

Comment: No; a Kafka topic is not a "queue"; it is a set of parallel immutable logs; there is no way (that I am aware of) to achieve your use case with Kafka, aside from using a single partition. Even if you have a only single consumer consuming from multiple partitions, there is no way to get strict ordering across partitions.

Comment: I suppose I may need to stick to a single partition, but with robust replication design then.  Is that a best practice with Kafka?  My 2 main goals are 1) process messages in order and 2) never lose a message.

Comment: Your concern about single point of failure is trivially handled by just having replicas. As for throughput issues, even setting aside kafka, aren't you facing the same bottleneck at the consumer end? You can't use multiple consumers because messages need to be processed one by one. So really you're going to have the same throughput issues there.

I would personally rethink the requirement of a global order.

Answer (score 0):

> publishing messages with a sequentially-incrementing ID and consuming them in that same order

A single partition is the only way to accomplish this when using Kafka.

One alternative design, from a blockchain perspective, would be to key by wallet address, for example, then you have ordered events per wallet. But then if you have transactions between wallets, there is no guarantee the "other wallet" from that withdraw/deposit event-value will exist, so you will need some other state-store (e.g. KTable) for all known wallet addresses before fully processing such events.

> The topic with block data will never be purged. This will grow to several TB

Partition segments are not distributed. If you had one partition, that means you're limited to the size of one HDD.

Similarly, RocksDB or in-memory state-stores will have the same problem. But, the interface for those are pluggable and can be replaced, with some tradeoffs for processing ordering guarantees.